# mysql returns datapoint outside the conditions given

Tags: mysql

I passed this query to mysql table

```
SELECT metar_id, latitude, longitude
FROM  `metars` 
WHERE  `latitude` >=  '38.996666666667'
AND  `longitude` >=  '103.16666666667'
AND  `latitude` <=  '40.663333333333'
AND  `longitude` <=  '104.83333333333'
```

and it give me one row with the following data.
1) metar_id=997419  latitude=4.53  longitude=103.43

why am i getting a datapoint outside the boundaries?

Comment: what's the type on the lat/long fields? floats? doubles? varchar? if it's varchar, you'll want to switch to actual numerical fields

Comment: Can you include the table definition?

Comment: It's almost always better to use `x BETWEEN y AND z` than `x >= y AND x <= z` because it indexes better, and makes it easier to read.

Comment: Yes got the issue. Another developer had worked on the table schema. The fields' data type is varchar :/ Getting it corrected from the db admin!! Thanks lets see it solves the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by simply changing the data type of the fields from varchar to float.